# BizTalk "Equal functoid" in NADLoop1 segment

Tags: dictionary, xsd, biztalk, edi, biztalk-2009

I am using BizTalk 2009, and right now I am working on mapping EDI to an XML schema

My EDI file [DESADV] has Looping segment [NADLoop1] which has the record segments as follows:

```
NAD+SH+10011::9'
NAD+WH+10011::9'
NAD+SU+SUPPLIER1::9'
```

I only want to read the value from third record ["SU"] from NADLoop1

I tried with equal functoid, since the first record qualifier is "SH" it returns false and I see no "NAD" value in output XML.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you connected a looping functoid to the NADLoop1 and to the destination field?  Are you using a value mapping functoid linked to the Equal one?

Answer (score 1):

Connect NAD (not NADLoop1) to the destination node through a Looping Functoid.

Then connect NAD01 to the Equal Functoid with "SU", then connect the Equal Functoid to the destination node (same as the one connected to the Looping Functoid).

Comment: Really sorry for very late reply. I tried what you had suggested but no luck. Then I tried with Value Mapping [Flattening] functoid with Equal functoid and it worked. Thanks for your tip.